# Mining pool rewards erc-20 smarts contract

Tags: ether, cpp-ethereum, mining-pools, reward, liquid-staking

I was contacted from a girl of Singapore,she told me to join the website PETL.top,with 1k of buying USDT erc-20,every day I withdraw 30 dollar,but today I accept this partecipation for the claim the reward but nowhere was written that one time you accept if you don’t put the rest of money in my case 3674, they blocked for 180 days my money, how I to réclame my money, I contact them from the customer service of the website petl.top and send me to a telegram number service and they say I had to wait 180 days if I don’t put the rest of the money,what I have to do for to take back my 1325 USDT ? [image]

Answer (score 3):

Hate to be the one to say it, but you got scammed. As a general rule, if someone contacts you to give you free money, it's a scam.

Comment: Most likely, no. Your money is gone and you'll never see it again. I still advice you go to the police, they'll take the site down, and hopefully investigate the scam, which could lead to a trial where you _could_ get your money back, maybe, in a few years.